# How do I make a chunk of text into a string when it contains quotes?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to make some text a string but there are quotes in the text which interferes with it being a valid string. How do I make a string when it the text contains quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Just escape them using the [escape string `\`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp). For example:

`"this string has a "quote" in it"`

you would do:

`"this string has a \"quote\" in it"`